# $ABCD = I$ then $B^{-1} =?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I got this question in a practice book.

A,B,C and D are $n\times n$ matrices with non-zero determinant.

$ABCD = I$ , then $B^{-1}$ = ?

The answer to this was $B^{-1}= CDA$.

How was that answer arrived at ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$ABCD=I$, $BCD=A^{-1}$, $CD=B^{-1}A^{-1}$, $CDA=B^{-1}$.

Comment: Wow if you put it that way it makes a lot of sense , Thanks

Answer (score 10):

$(AB)(CD)=I \Rightarrow (CD)(AB)=I \Rightarrow (CDA)(B)=I \Rightarrow CDA=B^{-1}$.

**Edit:** Alternatively,
$(A)(BCD)=I \Rightarrow (BCD)(A)=I \Rightarrow (B)(CDA)=I \Rightarrow CDA=B^{-1}$.

Answer (score 5):

Since A, B, C, D all have non zero determinant this implies that their respective inverses exist.

It's really an exercise in matrix algebra and in particular matrix multiplication.

\begin{align}
ABCD &=I\\
AB &=D^{-1}C^{-1}\\
B &=A^{-1}D^{-1}C^{-1}\\
B^{-1} &=CDA
\end{align}

Comment: Aah, an important point to solving objective questions, "Since A, B, C, D all have non zero determinant this implies that their respective inverses exist." . Thanks .

Answer (score 4):

If $ABCD = I$, then $BCD = A^{-1}$, $BC = A^{-1}D^{-1}$, $B = A^{-1}D^{-1}C^{-1}$,
from which we get $B^{-1} = (A^{-1}D^{-1}C^{-1})^{-1} = CDA$.

Comment: This a bit more complicated, but still good to know . Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If $ABCD = I$, then we could find a somewhat cyclic relation between these matrices:
$$
ABCDA = A \Rightarrow BCDA = A^{-1}A=I
$$
by exploiting multiplication from left or right, in addition to that matrix and the inverse of a matrix can commute in a multiplication.

Doing the same trick leads us to: $CDAB = I, DABC = I$ also.

$BCDA = B(CDA)=I$ and $CDAB = (CDA)B = I$ give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix with  non-zero determinant and $AB=I$. Then we can say that $B$ is the inverse of $A$, and we can say that $B^{-1}=A$?

Using the same rules for $ABCD=I$, partion it in $(ACD)B=I$ and let $ACD=X$ so $XB=I$. Thus we can say that $B^{-1}=X$. Thus $B^{-1}=ACD$.

Comment: How do you go from $ABCD=I$ to $(ACD)B=I$? Matrix multiplication is, in general, not commutative.

Answer (score 0):

If $ A, B, C, D $ are $n \times n$ matrices with non-zero determinants, it means **inverse** exists for these matrices.

It's given- $$ABCD=I$$
Take inverse on both sides of the equation. This will result in-

$$ => (ABCD)^{-1} = I^{-1} $$
$$ => D^{-1}C^{1}B^{-1}A^{-1} = I $$
(The order reverses on taking the inverse.)

Since, matrix multiplication is not commutative, we need to maintain the order of matrix multiplication.

$\therefore$ Multiply $D$ from the left.
$$ DD^{-1}C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}=ID $$

Since, we know, for a $n \times n$ matrix A, $AI=A$
And, if A is non-singular matrix, then-  $A.A^{-1}=I$

$$=> C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}=D $$

Multiply $C$ from the left.
$$=> CC^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}=CD $$

$$=> B^{-1}A^{-1}=CD $$

Multiply $A$ from the right.
$$=> B^{-1}A^{-1}A=CDA $$

$$=> B^{-1}=CDA $$